# How to center react-dialog?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I try to create a simple resizable dialog but I don't know how to set properties on the dialog.

My code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Panel from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Panel'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button'
import CustomerDetails from './CustomerDetails'
import axios from 'axios'
import Dialog from 'react-dialog'

export default class Customers extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedCustomer: 1,
      isDialogOpen: false,
    }
  }

  //function which is called the first time the component loads
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getCustomerData();
  }

  //Function to get the Customer Data from json
  getCustomerData() {
    axios.get('assets/samplejson/customerlist.json').then(response => {
      this.setState({customerList: response})
    })
  };

  openDialog = () => this.setState({ isDialogOpen: true })

  handleClose = () => this.setState({ isDialogOpen: false })


  render() {
    if (!this.state.customerList)
      return (<p>Loading data</p>)
    return (<div className="addmargin">



      <div className="col-md-4">
        {
          this.state.customerList.data.map(customer => <Panel bsStyle="info" key={customer.name} className="centeralign">
            <Panel.Heading>
              <Panel.Title componentClass="h3"><b>{customer.name}</b></Panel.Title>
            </Panel.Heading>
            <Panel.Body>
              <p>{customer.information}</p>
              <p>{customer.fullkitcctv}</p>
              <p>{customer.additionalInfo}</p>
              <Button bsStyle="info" onClick={() => this.setState({selectedCustomer: customer.id

              })} >

                Вижте за подробности

              </Button>
              <p>За да видите съдържанието, отидете най-долу в сайта</p>
            </Panel.Body>
          </Panel>)
        }
      </div>

      <div className="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" onClick={this.openDialog}>Open Dialog</button>
                {
                    this.state.isDialogOpen && 
                    <Dialog
                        title="Dialog Title"
                        modal={true}
                        onClose={this.handleClose}
                        buttons={
                            [{
                                text: "Затвори",
                                onClick: () => this.handleClose()
                            }]
                        }>
                        <CustomerDetails val={this.state.selectedCustomer}/>
                    </Dialog>
                }
      </div>
    </div>)
  }
}
```

Picture [image: screenshot]

How to set property on react-dialog-npm. I visit website https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dialog but I cannot see any properties.
I visit the demo site but I cannot see the source code from there. https://mohitgupta8888.github.io/react-dialog/?selectedKind=React%20Dialog&selectedStory=isResizable%3Atrue&full=0&down=0&left=1&panelRight=0

I really need to set properties because the users cant see all content of my information when websites visited by phones or tablets.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding alignSelf: "center" to dialogue styles.

If this doesn't work then,

write the dialogue code in the outermost div having a full screen access and then add

`{
   alignSelf: "center" 
 }`

to dialogue styles.

Hope that it'll help you.